# Are there agreements in place between the EU and the US to facilitate trade in services?

Tags: international-trade, wto

What agreements are in place between the EU and the US to facilitate trade in services?

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to find a centralized page with all of these. There's at least one [US-EU "open skies" agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU%E2%80%93US_Open_Skies_Agreement) concerning aviation (services).

Comment: Also the Tokyo WTO round [did remove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Agreement_on_Tariffs_and_Trade#Tokyo_Round:_1973%E2%80%9379) some non-tariff barriers, but details are sketchy. The [GATS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Agreement_on_Trade_in_Services) came in force after the Uruguay round.